# Autocannon requests rate

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, performance-testing, load-testing

So I need to make some simple performance testing on an Http server, which includes simulating users load, and I would like to use autocannon.

For example I need to simulate 200 req/sec for 2 minutes to an endpoint (as a simple simulation of stress created by multiple users), so that's the config I tried:

```
const config = {    
  connections: 200,   
  duration: 120,     
  overallRate: 200,     
  timeout: 10 
};
```

But from the metrics I see, it seems like it doesn't maintain a rate of 200 **new requests** per second, but rather closer to 200 open requests every second...
So it starts with 200 and then drops and stays way below that number.
Generally the latency of the tested endpoint is ~4 seconds.
Is there any way to configure autocannon to repeatedly create a certain amount of new requests every second regardless of the currently waiting ones?

Comment: How do you intend to service 200 requests per second when the endpoint latency is 4 seconds?  How many requests can the endpoint have open at once?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The latency increases to 4 seconds at around 30 req/sec. I can’t tell whether the route is capable of servicing up to 200 at all, and if it is, what’s the latency breakdown. Or what’s how many requests can the endpoint have at once? These are some of the purposes of the load testing.

Comment: Well, the Autocannon documentation states that `connection` setting means the number of concurrent connections Autocannon can use for making requests.  Sounds like you're being limited by that number.

Comment: Correct, the issue is that it’s not stable on that number or even near it. When opening 200 concurrent connections I expected to get 200 new requests being sent every second but instead it just waits for responses and only after that generate more requests. 
What I would like to achieve is shooting requests at a certain static rate.